# How can I add header and footer in PDF page using phantom-html2pdf

Tags: express, coffeescript, html2pdf

I am unable to find way of adding header and footer in pdf page using [phantom-html2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom-html2pdf) with Express and Coffeescript. My code is as follows can you please review it and tell me what I am missing:

```
    pdf = require('phantom-html2pdf')    
    exports.test_pdf = (req, res) ->
      paperSize = {
        format: 'A4',
        margin: "1cm",
        orientation: 'portrait'
        header: {
          height: "200cm",
          contents: '<h1>This is the Header</h1>'
        },
      }

      htmls = '<html><body><h2>PDF CONTENT</h2></body></html>';

      options = {
        html: htmls,
        css: "./public/stylesheets/foundation.css",
        paperSize : page.paperSize
      }
      pdf.convert options, (err, result) ->

        if !err
          result.toBuffer()
          # Using a readable stream
          result.toStream()

          # Using the temp file path */
          result.getTmpPath()

          # Using the file writer and callback */
          result.toFile("./html/pdf_file.pdf")
        else
        res.render('index', { title: 'Social Media'})
```

I have already done some research that to add header and footer, I need to export a paperSize object from a runnings file. https://github.com/bauhausjs/phantom-html2pdf/issues/30
but adding that too could not help me or I am not adding it correctly.

A little help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

module.exports will resolve your problem. After creating the page object for header & footer. you will export the object with module.export.

Here is the sample code

```
module.exports = {
    header: {
        height: '3cm', contents: function (page) {
            return '<header class="pdf-header" style=" overflow:hidden; font-size: 10px; padding: 10px; margin: 0 -15px; color: #fff; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00396f;"><img style="float: left;" alt="" src="../images/logo.jpg"><p> XYZ </p></header>'
        }
    },

    footer: {
        height: '3cm', contents: function (page) {
            return '<footer class="pdf-footer" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: #000;><p style="margin: 0">Powered by XYZ</p></footer>'
        }
    },

}
```

**Note**: You need to create runing file and copy & paste given code in it.

Comment: can you explain it further please.I'm trying but i cant make it work.
here is my code
**running.js**
`module.exports = {
    footer: {
        height: '3cm',
        contents: function(page) {
            return '<footer class="pdf-footer" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: #000;><p style="margin: 0">Powered by XYZ</p></footer>'
        }
    }
}`

**options object**

`var options = {
        "html": htmlReport,
        "css": './transactions/bootstrap.css',
        "delay": 2000,
        "runnings": './transactions/runnings.js'
    };`